# How to disable CORS checks for a specific source page

Tags: http, cross-domain

I have a situation where my web app (let's call it page A) fetches data from another server (call it B) via `XmlHttpRequest`s.

Server B runs on a different domain so we have a cross-origin request situation here.

The problem is that server B or particularly the queried API does not (yet) have CORS enabled. So requests from my web app fail:

[image: CORS error message]

Is there a possibility to disable CORS policy checks for requests from my source page A?

Update: I do not have control over server B, only page A.

Comment: How about just adding a service to the server of page A and let it call the service of server B?

Comment: The console log you posted is written by the browser. The browser blocks access to other than the originating domain. You can check in the network section if a server call was initiated or not. There are plug ins that disable this security feature and let you call services from another server.

Answer (score 0):

Modify servers htaccess file if you have [apache server](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following implementation to avoid the scenario:
Allow everything: probably not what you want

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

or

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [SCHEME]://[HOST]:[PORT_OPTIONAL]
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but should't the be applied to the target server (B)? As far as I know, doing this for the source page A will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Envoy (or Istio, which uses Envoy itself if you are on Kubernetes) for this. You can let Envoy programmatically apply the cors filter only to certain paths based on certain triggers such as the route destination, source of the request, the existence of some header key or value, or just about any other aspect of the request that you can think of.

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/cors_filter

Answer (score 0):

For testing you could start chrome without CORS:

Windows:

```
call chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data dir=D:\chromeBeta_disable_web_sec_userDataDir
```

Obviously this helps only during development. To run the page A in production the API on server B has to provide a correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.